# Samsung Galaxy S4 Sound and Shot Feature

Tags: android, android-camera

With the **SOUND AND SHOT** : **LISTEN TO YOUR PHOTOS** feature:

> Every picture you take on the Samsung Galaxy S4 can come with sound. So now you can remember what was said, played and heard not just what it looked like.

Now, I want to add this feature in my Android Application, in which I capture image from camera yet but now I want to capture with sound as above feature does. And, if I can do this then in which form that file will save, will it be an image or flash or a video and what will be extension for that file ?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: a simple idea would be save your photo with sound in a db and whenever you load your photo, play that sound accordingly.

Comment: @Raynold : I don't think this would be way to do it because of heavier database of sounds only.

Comment: @ManishAndroid, read my comment properly, **a simple idea**, means for starting the coding... i replied my first thought after reading your question that's it.

Comment: @ManishAndroid, i have worked on same kind of project where i show a small piece of textual information along with photo which was inserted before taking the photo, so same kind of idea here, only data type is changed from text to byte array, and mind it sound should be very less amount's like 5-10 seconds.

Comment: @Raynold : I appreciate your comments and work but I think this was not so easy in the case of capturing image with sound and show images in gallery view with sound. Try this with Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: why **with** , record a sound before or after taking image :) that would be same kind of feature :)

Comment: In feature, sound record when you capturing image not before not after.

Comment: @ManishAndroid, that's really kool, they may be handling camera & mic both activity togather.

Comment: I made a similar app for iPhone at http://www.pikspeak.com/ I kept it as an image concatenating to an audio was simple while parsing the image as compared to converting it to a video

Comment: @Raynold how can we show the sound plus image if we store the audio sound and image in the database